# unsigned long 0 < -1?

Tags: c

I don't get this one!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned short t1 = 0, t2 = 0;

    if( t1 < t2-1 )
        printf(" t1 < t2-1\n");

    unsigned long s1 = 0, s2 = 0;

    if( s1 < s2-1 )
        printf(" s1 < s2-1\n");
}
```

this results in:

```
 s1 < s2-1
```

Either both should fail or both not. I tried this with gcc 4 & 4.2

Comment: ~nairboon: I hope you don't mind the edit.  The code I replaced yours with is functionally the same, but can be copy/pasted into an editor and compiled without change.

Comment: Note that this result is not guaranteed to be the outcome. On machines where int stores the same value range as short (16 bit machines will, i think), you will see output for both ifs, because promotion will convert to unsigned int then, instead of to int.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C language performs the "Usual arithmetic conversions" for many operators - the conversions are outlined in 6.3.1.8 of the C99 standard.  For integral operands, first promotions are performed, and this is what's causing your issue.  The promotions are outlined in 6.3.1.1 (Arithmetic operands/Boolean, characters,and integers), which says among other things:

> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise,  it  is  converted  to  an  unsigned  int.  These  are  called  the  integer promotions.  All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

The promotions are applied only to objects or expressions with an integer type with a rank less than `int` and `unsigned int` (or bitfields).

So in your exression:

```
t1 < t2-1
```

even though the variables are `unsigned short` they are promoted to int, since on your platform `int` can represent all the values of `unsigned short`.  So the expression is evaluated using `int` types, and no underflow occurs - the `t2-1` part of the expression ends up as negative 1.

In the expression:

```
s1 < s2-1
```

the `unsigned long` types aren't promoted, because they have a higher 'rank' than `int`/`unsigned int`, so the expression is evaluated using unsigned arithmetic (with the underflow from the subtraction), and the `s2-1` subexpression evaluates to a very large number, not negative 1.

As litb indicated in a comment, if the platform had `int` implemented as a 16-bit type (which is permitted - MS-DOS for example), the promotion of `unsigned short` would be to `unsigned int` instead of `int`, since an `int` wouldn't be able to represent all values of `unsigned short` (`unsigned short` must be at least 16-bits).  In that case, both `if` statements would evaluate to true.

Answer (score 13):

Iam not sure but I suspect that the expression t2-1 automatically widened into an int value.
I do not have the c standard here what the exact conversion rules are, but I believe types smaller than int are automatically widened.

Comment: +1, in an arithmetic expression, objects of types (signed/unsigned) short and (signed/unsigned/) char are *promoted* to int.

Comment: This answer would be much better if you said **`t2`** is converted to int, not **`t2-1`** (so that it's clear that the conversion happens *before* the subtraction), though.

Answer (score 3):

C coercions, as you're discovering, are not always obvious, whenever you operate between different types. `t2` is u16, `1` is `int` (presumably 32-bits), so `t2-1` is exactly such an "operation between different types" and results in an overall coercion to int (as it's "longer" than u16...). Later, as s2 and 1 are both 32-bits (though of different signedness), the overall coercion is to unsigned long. So, the sizes of the types involved do help determine the signedness of the overall coercion.

I suggest avoiding mixed-signedness (and ideally also mixed-size!) operations (via casting or special literal notation for literals such as `1` that otherwise will have `int` type and make your life potentially complicated and your code potentially unportable;-).

Answer (score 0):

-1 is represented as all 1s. Therefore when interpreted as unsigned, its value is 2^32-1, which is clearly greater than 0. I'd guess that the first comparison is getting expanded to perform 32-bit signed arithmetic (perhaps due to the "1" being a signed int).

Note that the following WILL get to the printf, because the comparison is now done in 16-bit unsigned space again:

```
u32 temp = t2 - 1;
if( t1 < temp )
    printf(" t1 < t2-1\n");
```

Comment: The literal 1 (of type `int`) is converted to `unsigned long` before the subtraction. Since arithmetic on unsigned types is always performed modulo `2^k`, for type-specific `k`, the result is `2^k-1`. The representation of -1 is not involved (and it needn't be all ones on some architectures).

Comment: The representation of -1 is involved in explaining the second part: why 0 < -1 in unsigned longs.

Comment: No it isn't. Like avakar says, `-N` -> unsigned is a purely mathematically operation, which just computes `UINT_MAX+1 - N`. No representation is relied on anywhere.