# Conditional Appears False... Why is it True?

Tags: objective-c

Here's a couple lines of code... currentPage is an NSInteger, imageViewHolder is an NSMutableArray.

```
    NSLog(@"currentPage: %d, imageViewHolderCount: %d", currentPage, [imageViewHolder count]);
    if(currentPage < [imageViewHolder count] - 1)       
    {
        NSLog(@"%d < %d - 1", currentPage, [imageViewHolder count]);
        tempView = [imageViewHolder objectAtIndex:currentPage + 1];
        NSLog(@"doesn't get here, crashed.");   //this doesn't get logged because of crash.

        //do other stuff here
    }
```

I'm crashing at the "tempView = ..." line due to index out of bounds.  This is the output I'm getting:

```
currentPage: 0, imageViewHolderCount: 0
0 < 0 - 1
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x339bd88f 0x324af259 0x339069db 0x48f1b 0x48c1b 0x35603a85 0x35603409 0x35602c57 0x35716b0f 0x3560424d 0x4abfb 0x324ab175 0x43f77 0x45b91 0x479a7 0x36bff 0x285ed 0x35604ecb 0x32935933 0x33991a33 0x33991699 0x3399026f 0x339134a5 0x3391336d 0x32e91439 0x35608e7d 0xfa01 0xf9c0)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious... why is my if statement being evaluated as true?  I'm fairly certain that 0 is in fact greater than -1 :)

Comment: The count of an array is unsigned. What happens if you print `([imageViewHolder count] - 1)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `count` is an **unsigned** type. When you subtract `1` from an unsigned zero, you end up with a really large positive number<sup>1</sup> rather than `-1`.

Replace the condition with an equivalent expression that uses addition to avoid the problem:

```
if((currentPage+1) < [imageViewHolder count]) ...
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The value of `-1` in [2-s complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation used in most modern computers to represent negatives is a binary number composed entirely of ones. When this number gets re-interpreted as an unsigned 32-bit value, it becomes `2^32-1`.

Comment: Ooo! Awesome, thanks.  So simple now that you've pointed it out... I'll have to watch out for that when working with unsigned integers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but 0 is much less than MAX_INT. You're working with unsigned integers (I'd have to double-check the standard on whether this is defined as MAX_INT, or undefined behavior that happens to be MAX_INT, but in either case it's never what you mean). I suspect if you look at your compiler output, there's a warning to this effect (never allow any warnings in ObjC code).

See also [unsigned long 0 < -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415525/unsigned-long-0-1)

Comment: Thanks.  There is not a compiler warning, however.  Good read on that other thread though.

Answer (score 0):

this is a long shot ... but try writing your condition like this:

```
(currentPage < ([imageViewHolder count] - 1))
```

maybe the problem is that the compiler is grouping it like this

```
((currentPage < [imageViewHolder count]) - 1)
```

(0 < 0) returns false (0), then substracts 1, and stays at -1, which is different from 0, so it returns true